# Mixing up NodeJS & AngularJS. Is this the right approach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I'm in a bit of a confusion here. I'm making use of 3rd party REST APIs in my AngularJS app. 
One of the issues I faced is in order to use one of the user registration REST API, it required to authenticate using an authentication username and password.

***Doubt 1:*** I used NodeJS to make call the user registration REST API, since it exposed the authentication username and password from the AngularJS app. Is it the right approach?

***Doubt 2:*** Since I'm using NodeJS too, so I'm redirecting using the server sides. So, I'm not really making use of the AngularJS ngView. Is it the right approach?

Comment: I am confused too. you have two technologies on the server? python and nodejs?

Comment: No, I don't. Using a third part REST API which is developed using Python.

Comment: so you have a python web server. right? and you connect to it from angular on the client, right? where does nodejs come in?

Comment: actually, in order to use one of the API, I need to provide an authentication username and password. If I make the call from AngularJS, the username and password could easily be accessed from the browser, by any one. So, to restrict access, I made use of NodeJS for that particular API call.

Comment: @akonsu any thoughts ?